# How to extract data from table with different amount of spaces in between in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

I would like to extract data from a .txt file that looks similar as following:

[image]

This is part of the output generated by npm outdated --long=true > src/assets/data/dependencies.txt.

I was able to split the result into rows by using  **data.split('\n')**, but I am not sure how could I split the columns as the space between them seems to differ and additionally, some of the columns like, **"Depended by"** is built by two words and one space between. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Provide the text in the question, not as an image.

Comment: Blow off the first row, or use `.split(/ {2,}/)`

Comment: Thanks @RandyCasburn! It worked like a charm.